# What are few good algorithms for generating unique hashes of minimum length

Tags: string, hash, cryptography, compression

I am trying to shorten the MongoDB ObjectId, while keeping the uniqueness. I have few iot devices and i want to keep unique topics for every device to identify them individually. However, string length of default objectId is 24 and i want something short. Is there any hashing algorithm or some another technique to reduce the string size while keeping them unique.

Comment: Do you have multiple clients writing to the database? If not you can use a monotonic increasing counter in the one client. Otherwise you could use the "optimistic approach" - use small random counter and just use it. If the value is not unique Mongo will reject it (which should happen rarely therefore "optimistic"). If this happens try a second random number.

Comment: Hmm. Thank you Robert. I think this'll work.

Comment: Beware of the birthday problem and things slowing down to a halt when you are close to running out of ID's though. Oh, and the ObjectID is 12 bytes, the 24 characters are just the hexadecimal representation of those bytes. If you base64 encode them instead then you're already down to 16 characters instead of 24!